# F# -> C++/CLI problem: The namespace or module xxx is not defined, but F# -> C# -> C++/CLI is fine

Tags: .net, f#, c++-cli

Done a lot of googling but finding little info on `F# -> C++/CLI`

Very simple set up, in C++/CLI

```
namespace A {
public ref class B{
 public static void f(){};
}; }
```

In a C# project the namespace is visible can call `f()` fine:

```
A.B.f()
```

In an F# project the namespace is not visable and I get a compile error, and a red squiggly line under **A.**

If I wrap a call to `f()` in C# and then call that from F# all is ok.

I have made sure the build order is right and references set up. I can't see why F# is not behaving exactly like C#. Anyone got this working? Maybe some project setting needed in F#?

It is a pain to have to introduce a C# glue layer ?!?!?!

Comment: I don't know what's wrong in your example, but I have successfully used C++/CLI assemblies in an F# application, without problems. Maybe try `open A` and then `B.f()`?

Comment: Tried that I am afraid. Same error message. I have got VS2008 professional and v2.0.0.0 of the compiler - which I believe is the latest. It may be something wrong with the properties of the C++/CLI project ...

Comment: I used VS 2010 (or to be more exact: VS 2010 Shell + Visual C++ 2010 Express), same F# compiler version.

Comment: I can try downloading the VS 2010 shell at home - but my experience with the 2008 shell was that I could only use F# in the shell. How do you manage to use the shell and the express C++ 2010 together?

Answer (score 1):

OK it looks like a 2008 problem. A bug?

On my home PC I have downloaded VS C++ 2010 express and the 2010 shell and it works fine.

It took me a while to realise that it did not matter that I could not add my C++ project to my solution in the shell - i.e. I just needed to browse to the dll when adding a reference.

It is a bit of pain in the work environment since downloading the 2010 shell is probably not going to fly so I will have to make do with my work around of going via C# to get from F# to C++/CLI

Home is 64 bit btw.

Thanks for helping out.